# Setting enum values to 4-byte strings - why?

Tags: c, enums

I saw code similar to this in the Mac OS SDK:

```
enum {
   kAudioFileStreamProperty_ReadyToProducePackets    = 'redy',
   kAudioFileStreamProperty_FileFormat               = 'ffmt',
   kAudioFileStreamProperty_DataFormat               = 'dfmt',
   kAudioFileStreamProperty_FormatList               = 'flst',
   kAudioFileStreamProperty_MagicCookieData          = 'mgic',
   kAudioFileStreamProperty_AudioDataByteCount       = 'bcnt',
   kAudioFileStreamProperty_AudioDataPacketCount     = 'pcnt',
   kAudioFileStreamProperty_MaximumPacketSize        = 'psze',
   kAudioFileStreamProperty_DataOffset               = 'doff',
   kAudioFileStreamProperty_ChannelLayout            = 'cmap',
   kAudioFileStreamProperty_PacketToFrame            = 'pkfr',
   kAudioFileStreamProperty_FrameToPacket            = 'frpk',
   kAudioFileStreamProperty_PacketToByte             = 'pkby',
   kAudioFileStreamProperty_ByteToPacket             = 'bypk',
   kAudioFileStreamProperty_PacketTableInfo          = 'pnfo',
   kAudioFileStreamProperty_PacketSizeUpperBound     = 'pkub',
   kAudioFileStreamProperty_AverageBytesPerPacket    = 'abpp',
   kAudioFileStreamProperty_BitRate                  = 'brat'
};
```

It's the first time I've seen this - I assume the compiler assigns the 32-bit integer equivalent of the strings to the enum values. I cannot think of a single good reason why this might be preferred over using simple integers. It looks hideous in a debugger (how do you tell which of these values corresponds to `1919247481`?) and makes debugging just hard in general.

So, is there any reason where assigning such strings to enum values actually makes sense.

Comment: I don't understand the multi-character character literal

Comment: A multi-character integer character constant is allowed (by C99 at least), but the value is implementation-defined (section 6.4.4.4).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's precisely *because* of the debugger that you would do such a thing.  Most debuggers can show memory as ASCII, something like:

```
00000000: 12 34 56 78 90 12 45 67 12 34 56 78 89 ab cd ef .4Vx..Eg.4Vx....
```

Being able to identify structures, constants, and so forth by just looking at a memory dump is pretty handy.  Particularly if one of these structures and/or constants overwrote a bunch of memory you didn't want it to....

Comment: Ah. I don't think I've ever needed to view the value of an enum field in a memory window for a live debug session, but I guess this could be helpful in offline memory dumps. Different endian-ness would definitely makes it hard/impossible to use though.

Comment: @psychotik, memory stompers are the best case.  Imagine a structure filled with such enumerations blowing over your stack.  Now when you look at memory with the debugger, you can hope to identify what happened.  Endianness is not *that* big a deal - you get used to reading them backwards.

Answer (score 3):

That format is called a four-character code, or [`FOURCC`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FourCC). Incidentally, it originated from Apple with the Macintosh, and it's pretty convenient if you can view memory in ASCII characters. It's also a convenient way to embed 4-byte identifiers in a file, although it will look backwards given a little-endian convention.

Answer (score 0):

In gdb, you can check the constant by doing:

```
print (char[4]) val
```

Although on Intel and other little-endian systems the characters will be reversed. Older Macintosh computers that used PowerPC or 68k processors would show the characters in the correct order when viewing a memory dump.